# Angular filter in NodeJs view

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a table in node.js

```
 <%for(var i=0;i<listImages.length;i++){ %>
                  <tr>
                      <td><%=listImages[i].id%></td>
                      <td><%=listImages[i].imagename%></td>
                  </tr>
            <%  }  %>
```

How can I apply filtering from the Angularjs tables to such a table?

```
          <tr ng-repeat="items in listImages |filter:searchText">
                    <td>{{items.id}}</td>
                </tr>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Two questions: how can I organize a cycle in the Angular style (if it is necessary for the filter to work), and how can I make the filter work?

Comment: first question, is `listImages` a list on `$scope` or is it exclusively a list on the server that is rendered before angularjs?  It's generally not a good idea to mix server side rendered elements like this with Angularjs;  make an API and use `$http.get` instead.

Comment: List render before angular.

Comment: Right, that’s not data angular can filter.